# Hive queries failing on Tez but succeeding on Map-Reduce when connecting from Beeline

Tags: hadoop, hive, mapreduce, amazon-emr, apache-tez

I am running into a weird error. I am running a simple select * query with a where clause, following is the summary of query execution status

1. Connecting to Hive from EMR     (Tez engine) - succeeding
2. Connecting to Hive from EMR     (MR engine)  - succeeding
3. Connecting to Hive from Beeline (Tez engine) - failing
4. Connecting to Hive from Beeline (MR engine)  - succeeding

I need to solve for point 3.
This is the error trace I am getting and unable to find what the root cause of this failure is and what this error log is trying to convey.

````
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.Operation.toSQLException(Operation.java:380)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation.runQuery(SQLOperation.java:257)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation.access$800(SQLOperation.java:91)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation$BackgroundWork$1.run(SQLOperation.java:348)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1840)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation$BackgroundWork.run(SQLOperation.java:362)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)' SQL<select `ID`, `ISDELETED`, `ACCOUNTID`, `CREATEDBYID`, `CREATEDDATE`, `FIELD`, `OLDVALUE`, `NEWVALUE`, `AUDIT_UPD_TS`, `SRC_OP_TYP`, `GG_INGEST_TS` from `t4i_ent_sfdc_b2b_psa`.`sf_accounthistory` x WHERE SRC_OP_TYP='NA'>```
````

Comment: Can you please share beeline command you are using to invoke hive(beeline) session ? This will help understand if something is missing there.

Comment: Hi @AjayAhuja, I was able to resolve this and have posted the answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this. The problem was I was connecting my application to Hive via JDBC without specifying a user. For queries where simple streaming of data was required, it was succeeding, but where Map-Reduce jobs were being triggered to write to HDFS, the writing operation was failing with the error

```
Failed to execute tez graph.
    org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied: user=anonymous, access=WRITE, inode="/user":hdfs:hadoop:drwxr-xr-x
```

To resolve this, I added the user=hadoop; in the JDBC URL and the queries run fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Try invoking `beeline` (`Tez engine`) as below and then run your query :

```
beeline -u "jdbc:hive2://<host>:<port>,/;serviceDiscoveryMode=zooKeeper;zooKeeperNamespace=hiveserver2-batch?tez.queue.name=<yarn-queue-name>"
```

If above doesn't work then try to fix any issue in SQL. I see 'x' before Where clause in your sql query, that may be the issue. Try to remove that and run your query.

```
`sf_accounthistory` x WHERE SRC_OP_TYP='NA'
```

Hope this is helpful